# Skip csv header row using boto3 in lambda and copy_from in psycopg2

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, psycopg2

I'm loading a csv into memory from s3 and then I need to insert it into postgres. I think the problem is I'm not using the right call for the s3 object or something as I don't appear to be able to skip the header line.  On my local machine I would just load the file from the directory:

```
  cur = DBCONN.cursor()

  for filename in absolute_file_paths('/path/to/file/csv.log'):
      print('Importing: ' + filename)

  with open(filename, 'r') as log:
      next(log)  # Skip the header row.
      cur.copy_from(log, 'vesta', sep='\t')

  DBCONN.commit()
```

I have the below in lambda which I would like to work kind of like above, but it's different with s3. What is the correct way to have the below work like above? Or perhaps - what IS the correct way to do this?

```
  s3 = boto3.client('s3')

  #Load the file from s3 into memory    
  obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)    
  contents = obj['Body']

  next(contents, None) # Skip the header row - this does not seem to work
  cur = DBCONN.cursor()
      
  cur.copy_from(contents, 'my_table', sep='\t')
 
  DBCONN.commit()
```

Comment: check what data  you are getting in `contents = obj['Body']` and see if its in right format to  be parsable by `next`

Comment: I actually JUST figured out that when I do that it seemingly cuts the line off half way through and next() seems to get the second half o the first line.  The lines are extremely long in this csv.  Is there some way to fix that? Some way to tell next to look for \n instead of...I guess a byte length?

Comment: i dont think we can use `next()` like that.  But i suggest you check your file if some junk  or special character confusing the next() iterator.

Comment: There is no character (just checked with notepad++ with characters on).  It's chopping it right in the middle of the word.  Funny enough, when I open the file in normal notepad it chops it at exactly the same spot. If I hit backspace, it deletes one character from the word on the previous line but only puts in the one character. I guess notepad itself has a limit on size for a line?

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly, my problem had something to do with an incredibly wide csv file (I have over 200 columns) and somehow that messed up the next() function to not give the next row. SO! I will say that IF your file is not seemingly that wide, then the code I placed in the question should work. Below however is how I got it work, basically by just reading the file into memory and then writing that back to an in memory file after skipping the header row. This honestly seems a little like overkill so I'd be happy if someone could provide something more efficient but seeing as how I spend the last eight hours on this, I'm just happy to have SOMETHING that works.

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    ...

    def remove_header(contents):
        # Reformat the file, removing the header row
        data = csv.reader(io.StringIO(contents), delimiter='\t') #read data in
        mem_file = io.StringIO() #create in memory file object
        next(data) #skip header row
        writer = csv.writer(mem_file, delimiter='\t') #set up the csv writer
        writer.writerows(data) #write the data in memory to the in mem file
        mem_file.getvalue() # Get the string from the buffer
        mem_file.seek(0) # Go back to the beginning of the memory stream
        return mem_file

    ...

    #Load the file from s3 into memory
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    contents = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

    mem_file = remove_header(contents)

    #Insert into postgres
    try:
        cur = DBCONN.cursor()      
        cur.copy_from(mem_file, 'my_table', sep='\t') 
        DBCONN.commit()
    except BaseException as e:
        DBCONN.rollback()
        raise e
```

or if you want to do it with pandas

```
def remove_header_pandas(contents):
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(contents), sep='\t') 
    mem_file = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(mem_file, header=False, index=False) #remove header
    mem_file.getvalue()
    mem_file.seek(0)
    return mem_file
```